# Sampling Theorem for Lattices

Tags: reference-request, signal-processing

I am looking for a reference for an analogue of the Shannon sampling Theorem for more general lattices (in any dimension).

Something along the lines of the theorem in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_sampling

Looking at the original paper cited there was not so helpful, and I haven't found more modern references that deal with the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs across this and needs it, I did eventually find such a reference.
[I. Kluvanek, "Sampling theorem in abstract harmonic analysis," $\textit{ Mat. Casopis Sloven. Akad. Vien}$, 15 (1965), p. 43-48.]

This paper is also cited in
[H. Behmard, A. Faradini, and D. Walnut, "Construction of sampling theorems for unions of shifted lattices," $\textit{Sampling Theory in Signal and Image Processing}$ , Vol. 5, No. 3, (2006), p.297-319.]